# Visualizing network graph data in R (need library/data recommendations)

Tags: r, graph

This is my first foray into doing visualizations of network graph stuff, so bear with me.

I have data (it's currently in a .csv of 100k lines, but I can load it up in a SQL DB of some flavor) with the following info:

```
location_name, person_name, time_of_day (discretely broken up as: morning, noon, afternoon, night)
```

Some example rows:

```
park, David, noon
park, Tina, morning
cafe, John, night
cafe, Shirley, night
```

I'm thinking of treating of analyzing time across separate graphcs (so I'll have a morning graph, noon graph, etc.) -- and for all I care I can generate a chart of all times together and treat combinations of location-time as unique connectors, since my primary interest is the relation between the people in this data.

So given my data format, what functions and libraries would people recommend me looking into?  Also, if there are some golden standards of doing R graph stuff, what kind of data format would people recommend that I transform my current data into?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like this question. Here's what CRAN says: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html Also, see this similar question on the SE stats site: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/graph-theory-analysis-and-visualization

Comment: I guess I've seen a few of these libraries at this point: should I transform my dataset into a 2D, discrete integer-based representation of info instead, then figure out out to superimpose text/labeling info over the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a CRAN topic view for network/graph models.  Try the igraph package. as well.  But this question will likely be closed unless you make it considerably more specific....

Comment: How should I make this more specific?  Kindly let me know and I'll edit accordingly.

To reiterate my questions:
a) Given a .csv of data formatted in the way I specified, what library should I use?
b) If there are no libraries that work with the provided data format, what is the preferred format(s) such that I can transform my data into said format and use those libraries instead?

FWIW I'm checking out the igraph package right now...

Comment: I should probably have made my answer a comment instead.  Oh well.  Anyway, I'd drop part (b) since it's going to depend entirely on which graphing function you use.  I'm interested in other answers to this question as well, but I do think it's not really a programming question as currently posed, and thus off-topic for SO.  Possibly a great question on CrossValidated, but you should not double-post (let the mods migrate it).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say much about what you intend to do with the data. The cran packages [network](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) and [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) have plotting for static networks, [networkDynamic](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkDynamic/index.html) provides data structures for dynamic networks and can be used by [ndtv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ndtv/index.html) along with the [animation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) library to generate network movies.  Perhaps these suit your needs?